# Remove blue line from tab widget in android

Tags: android, qtabwidget

I have tried  both

```
android:tabStripEnabled="false"
```

and

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().setStripEnabled(false);
```

for removing the blue line from tab widget that appears bottom of tabwidget but no luck

is there something that I am missing

Comment: Hope This Helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647836/how-to-change-the-colour-of-actionbar-navigation-tabs/8647970#8647970

Answer (score -1):

Apply the theme on your `activity` in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application android:theme="@style/YourTheme">
```

and in `style.xml` the theme may be like this:

```
 <style name="YourTheme">  
       <item name="android:textColor">#5DFC98</item>
 </style>
```